# adding integers from each node of a tree

Tags: c, recursion, struct, tree

How would I be able to add data from different nodes together? `Inserttotree()` just creates a new node and enters the `data` value specified.

So basically I'm just trying to add `2` and `3` together in the `countquantity()` function.

```
typedef struct tree_s tree_t;
typedef int data_t;

struct tree_s {
    data_t data;
    tree_t *left;
    tree_t *right;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    tree_t *tree;
    tree = NULL;
    tree = insertToTree(tree, 3);
    tree = insertToTree(tree, 2);
    printf("Total: %d\n", countQuantity(tree));
    return 0;
}

int countQuanity(tree_t *tree){
    int i = 0;
    if(tree == NULL){
        return i;
    }

    i = tree->data + countQuantity(tree->left);
    i = tree->data + countQuantity(tree->right);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Just sum up two results of the subtrees and the current node like `i=tree->data + countQuantity(tree->left) + tree->data + countQuantity(tree->right)`

Comment: do you understand that somehow you're overwriting the value of `i` in `countQuanity()`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. post that as an answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeap, thanks. Lazy copy/paste..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a sum of the node's value and the computed values of both subtrees:

```
i=tree->data + countQuantity(tree->left) + countQuantity(tree->right)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look this part of your code,

```
i = tree->data + countQuantity(tree->left);
i = tree->data + countQuantity(tree->right); 
    //The value of i is being over written here
return i;
```

Your code should have been more like this,

```
i = tree->data + countQuantity(tree->left);
i += countQuantity(tree->right);
return i;
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. Corrected it ! Sorry ! That was a bad copy paste !